# How do I include math mode in a bibliography entry with ieee style?

Tags: math-mode, biblatex, biber, ieee-style

I just spent a while identifying that this one reference in my `bib` file was preventing compilation after running `bib mwe`.  I get the error: `! Extra }, or forgotten $.`. I found that it would compile when I changed the style to certain ones but not `ieee` nor `phys`.  The problem is the greek character \lambda in the title.  How can I get this citation to work with these biblatex styles?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{qiu_saltdependent_2011,
  title = {Salt-Dependent DNA-DNA Spacings in Intact Bacteriophage $\ensuremath{\lambda}$ Reflect Relative Importance of DNA Self-Repulsion and Bending Energies}, % ieee does not like math mode commands
  % title = {Salt-Dependent DNA DNA Spacings in Intact Bacteriophage lambda Reflect Relative Importance of DNA Self Repulsion and Bending Energies}, % runs fine
  author = {Qiu, Xiangyun and Rau, Donald C. and Parsegian, V. Adrian and Fang, Li Tai and Knobler, Charles M. and Gelbart, William M.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {106},
  issue = {2},
  pages = {028102},
  numpages = {4},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Jan},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.028102},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.028102}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
%  style=phys,       % ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
  style=ieee,       % ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
%  style=chem-acs,   % this one works
%  style=science,    % this one works
%  style=nejm,       % this one works
%  style=nature,     % this one works
%  style=chem-rsc,   % this one works
%  style=chem-angew, % this one works
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

test text here \cite{qiu_saltdependent_2011}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I compile this using the commands:

```
rm *.blg *.bib *.bbl *.aux -f && pdflatex mwe.tex && biber mwe && pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Comment: Below @egreg points out that the default behavior of [Zotero],(https://www.zotero.org/) or possibly the [BetterBibTex](https://zotplus.github.io/better-bibtex/citation-keys.html) plugin, to use ` $\ensuremath{\lambda}$` is what leads to the problem.  In Zotero, I had to change this part of the title to `<pre>{$\lambda$}</pre>` for the offending reference, to get it to export and then compile properly.  I believe it is a Zotero problem because I went to the webpage for the citation and used the import button in my browser and it loaded in the title with `$\ensuremath{\lambda}$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get no error if I use `{$\lambda$}`; I checked with both `style=phys` and `style=ieee`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{qiu_saltdependent_2011,
  title = {Salt-Dependent {DNA-DNA} Spacings in Intact Bacteriophage {$\lambda$} Reflect
           Relative Importance of {DNA} Self-Repulsion and Bending Energies},
  author = {Qiu, Xiangyun and Rau, Donald C. and Parsegian, V. Adrian and Fang,
            Li Tai and Knobler, Charles M. and Gelbart, William M.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {106},
  issue = {2},
  pages = {028102},
  numpages = {4},
  year = {2011},
  month = {Jan},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.028102},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.028102}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=phys,       % ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
%  style=ieee,       % ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
%  style=chem-acs,   % this one works
%  style=science,    % this one works
%  style=nejm,       % this one works
%  style=nature,     % this one works
%  style=chem-rsc,   % this one works
%  style=chem-angew, % this one works
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

test text here \cite{qiu_saltdependent_2011}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note also the braces around `DNA` so it is not lowercased.

The first picture is with `style=phys`, the second one with `style=ieee`.

### Output with `style=phys`

[image]

### Output with `style=ieee`

[image]

Comment: Any ideas why the `\ensuremath` part breaks it?  That is throughout the bib file I auto-generate using Zotero using the BetterBibTex addon.  (I will have to look into removing  that or putting a [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command in my makefile to remove it.)

Comment: @stvn66 `$\ensuremath{\lambda}$` is everything but a sensible thing to do. `;-)` The error has something to do with the steps for capitalization/uncapitalization. What's to be preserved in titles without any change should always be braced.