# BibTeX issue with math symbol bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I use TeXstudio to compile my documents and in the following case I keep receiving "error - Extra }, or forgotten $" followed by "error - Missing } inserted".

```
\begin{filecontents*}{source.bib}
    @article{Geiger1908,
       title = {An Electrical Method of Counting the Number of $\alpha$-Particles from Radio-Active Substances},
       author = {Rutherford, E. and Geiger, H.},
       journal = {Proceedings of The Royal Society A},
       volume = 81,
       issue = 546,
       pages = {143 -- 161},
       year = 1908,
       url = {http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/81/546/141}
     }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[style=phys,sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{source.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Geiger1908}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

From deleting contents section by section, I am certain the error come from the `title` field of the `Geiger1908` entry. But what is giving the error?

Comment: How is `\source` defined?

Comment: The pre-emble should define it? On my computer, I made a separate file named `source.bib` and use the `\addbibresource{source.bib}` command instead.

Comment: No, I don't think the math mode is the problem. Try removing the \ from the bib name, i.e. Use `\bibliography{source}` and `\begin{filecontents*}{source.bib}` instead. Is the error still present then?

Comment: If I change the two instances of `\source` to just `source` (without the backslash), I experience no problems whatsoever compiling your example. Incidentally, for the instruction `\addbibresource{source.bib}` to work, the `biblatex` package must be loaded. Is that the case? If it is, why does your code feature `bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` instructions? For sure, there's nothing wrong at all with the `title` field of the `Geiger1908` entry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. The code should say "source", not "\source".

Comment: The error exists for a separate file. So it's not the typo

Comment: What do you mean by "separate file" here? Anyway, I cannot reproduce the problem either, do you really get that error from the code in the question? (try it in a new file, or delete all auxiliary files before recompiling) If not, can you try to make an example that does reproduce the error?

Comment: Ok. I will try deleting all aux files first. Thank you

Comment: Edited accordingly. I am still getting the error on my end after recreating the aux files. Not sure what to do

Comment: What happens if you insert the instruction `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` immediately before `\begin{filecontents*}{source.bib}`, and then fully recompile?

Comment: With the new edit, there's no problem at all. Please copy the example to a completely new directory and compile there (and don't forget to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`) to avoid problems with old `bib`-, `aux`-, `bbl`- or `bcf`-file.

Comment: @Mico You should warn the OP that `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` destroys an existing `source.bib`. Unfortunately and against all recommendations, users often did not use a separate directory for tests but the real document directory.

Comment: I can't get the `\printbibliography` command to work in the new file for some reason.. Still trying to fix it.

Comment: I found the source of the error. I used `style=phys` in `biblatex` (edited the question accordingly) and it is somehow incompatible with math symbols. I am remembering the same issue in the past vaguely now. But I can't remember how I got around it..

Comment: Use `{$\alpha$}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271119/how-do-i-include-math-mode-in-a-bibliography-entry-with-ieee-style/271121#271121

Comment: Thank you! That combined with deleting all auxiliary files worked.

Comment: This is a bit pedantic, but should the alpha in "alpha particle" be typeset in math mode? I thought alpha was being used as a name here, not a mathematical expression.

Comment: That's a good point. I remember seeing both in journal article titles.